# PHP object and methods - does $object->method request data or just store it

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I have a query which requests data and returns an array called $result.

```
class data {

    public function __construct ($type) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }


      function set_url($url) {
            // Construct URL based on type.
       return $this->url;
       }

        function curl_data($url) {

    $url = $this->set_url(); //Run the set_url function to work out the url of the object

        $options = array (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER => etc ); // stop after 10 redirects

        //Initiatiate the connection
        $ch = curl_init ( $url );
        curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
        //Capture the content
        $content = curl_exec ( $ch );
        $err = curl_errno ( $ch );
        $errmsg = curl_error ( $ch );
        $header = curl_getinfo ( $ch );
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

        curl_close ( $ch );

        $header ['content'] = $content;
        return $header ['content'];
      }
    }
```

I can then call this data by using:

```
   $object = new data('type1');
   $object->curl_data(); //Select the URL, Process the api call, return the content
```

All works this far. However, when I then decode the json with a similar function inside the data class, I hit an error because I'm requesting too much data from the server.

```
    public function decode_json($response){

            //$this->curl_data();

        //manipulate the response
        $response = json_encode($response,true);
        $response = json_decode($response); 

    return $response;
    }
```

I think this is because my decode function carries out a **new** curl_data() call - rather than just using the data which has already been retrieved. I've tried using both of the following approaches to call the decode function and am not sure which one broke it / how to make it work.

```
 $object->decode_json($object->curl_data()); //with $decode_json escaping $this->curl_data(); and requesting ($response)

 $object->decode_json(); //with decode_json() using $this->curl_data(); and not requiring ($response)
```

My question is - **How does my $object->curl_data(); query actually work** and how can I avoid multiplying up the queries by referencing it in a way that re-requests data from the server. This comes to light with JSON queries, but probably also results in serious performance issues if I do it wrong when requesting from my own databases etc.

It seems that the '->' syntax results in extra queries through the method - rather than just storing the data, but if I just store the data in a variable I wouldn't be coding to OOP principles.

Comment: Did you write the function `curl_data()`?

Comment: Yep. Sorry just made that clearer in the post. I'm puzzled as to how I can avoid a reference of $object->decode_json(); which will be dependent upon curl_data(); from requesting the data twice - once in each.

Comment: OK, so what part of it do you not understand how it works? It opens a connection, fetches data, closes the connection and returns that data.

Comment: I understand that much - I can't work out how to change $object->decode_json($object->curl_data()); to just a single call to 'decode_json(); that has curl_data(); within it, without overloading the server by asking for multiple sets of data from it. In particular, since I only want to carry out the curl_data() function once, but I might want to do lots of things to the data afterwards - and risk calling the decode_json function, or other ones which are dependent upon it more than once...

Comment: Can you add the error too, please?

Comment: @tpb - at the moment it just says 'Developer Over Rate' - I know that the actual code delivers the right information to the browser... but everytime I manipulate the result from curl_data(); (it contains some figures which I do calculations on), I think it re-requests the initial api call and is overloading the server. At the moment I have a decode_json function, and also a calculate_figures method - both accessing the curl_data(); response in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want:

```
$result1 = $object->curl_data();
$result2 = $object->decode_json($result1);
$result3 = $object->calculate_figures($result1);
```

do curl_data only once and handle the result with 2 different methods.